# NetBeans auto-completion from included file not working?

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

I have a file named config.php, and i have other files includes config.php. When editing one of files, I use an object from config.php and it autocompletes name of the object. But, when i try to see functions or variables of this object (with ->), there is no auto-completion. Is there any way to make it work?

Note: I already added /* @var $myObject myType */ to config.php before the object definition. Do I have to add that line to my every file includes config.php? That doesn't seem right.

Edit: Sample added.

Directory;

- config.php
- index.php
- lib/test.class.php

config.php;

```
<?php
define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__));
include_once ABSPATH.'/lib/test.class.php';

/* @var $TestObj test */
$TestObj = new test();

// auto complete works here.
$TestObj->someFunction();
?>
```

index.php;

```
<?php
include_once 'config.php';

// here, auto completes object name
// not lists functions or variables after ->
$TestObj->someFunction();
?>
```

lib/test.class.php;

```
<?php
class test {
    public $var1;

    public function someFunction() {
        echo 'I am some function.';
        return 0;
    }
}
?>
```

It is working when i add /* @var $TestObj test */ to index.php but I will have a lot of files like that and there must be a better way than adding that line to all of files.

Comment: does it auto-complete in config.php ? Are you certain taht in other files you are using this variable in the same scope, and not overwriting it with non-object ?

Comment: Yes, it is working in config file and I am sure there is no overwriting. When completing object _name_, it shows config.php on the right top corner. I added a sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make shure that all files of your project are in the project's include path (righ click project -> properties -> include path). Usually there is only the "global include path", which you configure in the NetBeans settings (e.g. to point to your PEAR directory). Add all directories which contain source code you want auto completion for to this include path. Hint: This include path has nothing to do with the include_path used in PHP itself.

Also instead of using hints in the cient code:

```
/* @var $TestObj test */
$TestObj->...
```

You should give the sources some more apidoc, e.g.:

```
<?php
class test {
    /**
     * @var SomeClass
     */
    public $var1;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function someFunction() {
        echo 'I am some function.';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

because of the dynamic nature of PHP the IDE realies on this information to give right hints.

Comment: I set the include path, still nothing. If you send me an example which you are sure it is working, I can try it to see if problem is about IDE or technique.

Comment: @m_poorUser: Clone https://github.com/Weltraumschaf/ebnf and open the subfolder `php` with NetBeans. It should work out of the box. The config for NetBenas is stored in the `nbproject` dir.

Comment: I import the project, checked the configuration files, exactly same. Then i tried this; in folder src/EBNF/ There is a Scanner.php file, added this line to file; "$Scan = new Scanner();" Then I opened Command.php file which requires Scanner.php, I wrote $Scan->, there is no suggestions. Is my technique wrong or is my IDE broken?

Comment: m_poorUser First: Don't use global vars like you do (declare in one file and use in other) that's very bad style and error prone. I've never did this, so I don't know if this will work in NetBenas. Second: Don't use active code in a config file. Inside a config file there should be onluy config, no executable code (function/method invocation and such), because of testability. What works: Open `Parser.php` and type inside a method `$this->scanner->` and you wil get intelli sense. Other pro tip: Use PhpStorm from JetBrains. It's a way way better  IDE than NetBenas for PHP.

Answer (score 8):

Go to Tools->Options-> click on PHP Icon on top -> General tab -> find "Global include path"
-> Add Folder ->

if(onLinux) { choose /var/www; }
if(onWindows) { choose c:\path_to_htdocs or whatever; }

Ah, too much programming for today.. :)

For me, this repaired autocompletion and ctrl+click on method call.

Comment: Just came here to say that, this solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

From netbeans go to `tools->options`
Go to editor selection and from code Completion select php for languages section. This will expand menu and you will see a section `Code Completion for Class Methods`

Set that configuration by selecting checkboxes on that section.
[image]

I hope I understood this right. I use netbeans too and I am able auto-complete after I change my netbeans settings.

Comment: It is already checked. Auto-complete for class methods works on same file, but, if the object is from an included file, that does not work. BTW my NetBeans version is 7.0.1. If my example works on another version of NetBeans (maybe on your version), I can check this answer as right one.

Comment: I am using 7.0.1 too. I have an init file which loops through folders and adds needed classes and I get auto-complete box to show me available functions on ctrl+space. Only difference I see in this case is my class names don't have name.<class>.php kind of notation. My class names match file names.

Comment: When NetBeans start, status bar says "Scanning Projects". So I assume it is looking for classes, methods etc. I didn't change a setting about that. I tried renaming class file with name of class it contains , didn't work. I think you may be misunderstood the question. I see auto-complete menu, but, if only the object is in the file I am working on. If this is working for you, that means I am doing something really wrong. Please try the sample I send and let me know if auto-complete is working on index.php file.