# Netbeans does not autocomplete PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

I have a new PC with Windows 10 and Netbeans 8.2 installed and transferred my HTML5 projects from my old PC. For some reason, Netbeans no longer works to auto complete any PHP function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAq07.png)

If I do the same on my old PC it presents "max" as possible option for auto completion. What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you opening an individual file or opening as a PHP project?
Other way is to follow: Tools -> Editor -> Code Completion -> PHP

Comment: its a PHP file within the HTML project. I just checked and it works as expected when I have the whole project as PHP project but why doesn't it work anymore when its a PHP file within the HTML project?

Comment: also checked the code completion settings for PHP - looks all good.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157133/netbeans-auto-completion-from-included-file-not-working